# Blueprint doesn't affect its parent - Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have C++ Character class called `VRCharacter` with the attributes programmed in C++ as follow:

```
VRRoot = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("VRRoot"));
VRRoot->SetupAttachment(GetRootComponent());

Camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("Camera"));
Camera->SetupAttachment(VRRoot);

DestinationMarker = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("DestinationMarker"));
DestinationMarker->SetupAttachment(GetRootComponent());
```

And I have created a blueprint with the `VRCharacter` as its parent and when I open the blueprint, i can see all the attributes I declared in the code as shown below:
[image: VRCharacter Blueprint]

And I can see on the top right written that the parent is `VRCharacter`
[image: Parent Class]

But when I play the game and navigate to the `VRCharacter` in the scene, I don't see all the attributes, I can only see the `Mesh` and the `DestinationMarker` as shown in the picture below:
[image: VRCharacter while in play mode]

And when I apply some changes to the `DestinationMarker` from the blueprint such as changing the `Static Mesh`, it doesn't get applied to the `VRCharacter` in play mode.

**Why my blueprint doesn't affect its parent?** is there anything I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you added the C++ class to the scene instead of your blueprint 'subclass'. Try dragging your BP_VRCharacter into the scene, and the world outliner should display 'BP_VRCharacter' as type instead of 'VRCharacter'